# Regex to get the last match of a pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Here is a string similar to what I'm trying to match (with the exception of a couple of specific patterns, for the sake of simplicity).
`Hello, tonight I'm in the town of Trenton in New Jersey and I will be staying in Hotel HomeStay [123] and I have no money.`

I'm trying to match only the last `in Hotel HomeStay [123]`.

I'm not very familiar with regex concepts like lookahead and lookbehind right now. Similar questions here don't seem to solve my issue. I've tried a bunch of regex (to the best of my understanding) and this is what I came up with `(?= (?:in|\d+))([\w \[]*\s*\d*\]*)(?!.*in)`. The digits and special characters may be part of what I'm actually trying to match.

The lookahead and lookbehind patterns are not restricted to containing only `in`. They can have more common words as well such as `and` and `is`. I'm only looking for the last occurence of any of these, followed by the main pattern, which is quite distinctive -- **edit** let's say the match should necessarily contain either `HomeStay` or `LuxuryInn`, for the sake of the example.

However, this matches the whole of `in the town of Trenton in New Jersey and I will be staying in Hotel HomeStay [123]`.
Where am I going wrong? Also, could someone explain why the `in` is captured despite being placed in a non-capturing group?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not possible with regex. Sorry!

Comment: @Ava Oh, that's a bummer.  I edited my original post to add a few more details, if that helps. Are there any other tools I could check out for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve a text containing `HomeStay` prefixed by certain words and not containing those words, you can use a capture group using negative look-ahead inside. The regex below captures all occurrences ([working fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/dAymF5/17)).

```
\b(?:in|and|is)\s+((?:.(?!\b(?:in|and|is)\b))*HomeStay(?:.(?!\b(?:in|and|is)\b))*)
```

Here, the regexp looks for :

- a given prefix (`in`, `and` or `is` as a *whole* word, surrounded by word breakers **`\b`**)
- ... followed by at least one blank character,
- ... then a sequence of 0 or more characters *each one not followed by a prefix*,
- ... followed by `HomeStay`,
- ... followed by another  sequence of 0 or more characters, *each one still not followed by a prefix*

If you just want the last occurrence, you can add another negative look-ahead after ([fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/dAymF5/18)).

```
\b(?:in|and|is)\s+((?:.(?!\b(?:in|and|is)\b))*HomeStay(?:.(?!\b(?:in|and|is)\b))*)(?!.*HomeStay.*)
```

Same as above, except the matched text must not be followed by a text containing `HomeStay`.

Finally, if the matching text has to contain at least a word from a list, just replace both occurrences of `HomeStay` with a list of alternatives. Example for HomeStay and Luxury: `(?:HomeStay|Luxury)` ([fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/dAymF5/19)).

Comment: Basically, I want the smallest substring that these conditions would match. Prefixed immediately with "in", and containing "HomeStay". So I guess I want the former: the last occurrence of a text prefixed by "in" and it has to contain HomeStay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223717/discussion-between-ad-ve-and-amessihel).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In java:

```
String s = "Hello, tonight I'm in the town of Trenton in New Jersey and I will be "
           + "staying in Hotel HomeStay [123] and I have no money.";
// Garbage: final String SUBP = "\\bin\\s+(\\S+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*\\sin\\s+(\\S+).*$", Pattern.DOTALL);
String last = p.matcher(s).replaceFirst("$1"); // If found
```

This will find the **last** "... in ...", as `.*` (instead of eager `.*?`) will look for the longest sequence.

The result above will be `Hotel` (non spaces afer `in`) but it may be anything.

---

- Dot-All will effect that `.` also matches line break characters.
- The pattern will go from beginning `^` to end `$`.
- Any characters `.*` (most longest) followed by a whitespace char `\s`.
- Then "in ", then a word (non-spaces `\S+`) in group 1 `(...)`
- Then any chars till the end `.*`. For purity it should have been `.*?` for the shortest sequence.
- The End `$`.

Comment: Could you explain it in a little detail? Especially the purpose of string SUBP?

Comment: My first idea was making a repeating pattern with `(.*" + SUBP + ").**(" + SUBP + ")"` so $2 was the desired regex group. Now it is garbage which I should have deleted.

Comment: I see. I tried this out, and while it works for the particular case of matching "Hotel", as soon as I include a space to capture multiple words, it will also include the "and ..." till the end of the sentence, which I'm trying to avoid. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you have a list of such words a _negative look-ahead/look-behind_ can be used. Also you can limit the number of words with ``(\\S+(\\s+\\S){0-3})`. As such regex things easily become unreadable, coding it should be considered too - probably faster.